# How to get around DynamoDb BatchGetItem

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have thousands of keys to retrieve from Dynamo DB each key will get 1 item its based on primary key.
But BatchGetItem has limitations on number of keys we could pass which is just 100. Any better way to pull thousands ?

Comment: Nope. That is the limitations you have to work with. I sincerely hope this isnt a regular access pattern or someone made some very wrong choices in the set up of this dynamo.

Comment: @lynkfox - you're correct, please add this as an actual answer - comments bypass the quality control mechanisms of the platform (i.e. voting).

Comment: done! I was making an opinionated comment in there as well which is why i did not initially add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to bypass this hard limit. You can loop through it and make multiple calls of course, but for a single batch command you cannot bypass this limit.